# Conditional Formatting from 2 columns

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to change the colour of a cell if 2 conditions are true: 1. The date in the `G` column is before today, and 2: The value in column `AM` is `"DISPATCH"`.

I have managed to change the to get a simple code for the Date which is: `=$G$11<TODAY()`, which works.

The code I am using for AM column is `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SHIPPED",AM11))=FALSE` - I Think something is going wrong here?

Comment: L column, please. (L5:L44)

Answer (score 0):

Please select from L5 to L44, then HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(G5<TODAY(),AM5="""DISPATCH""")
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select colour, OK, OK.

Comment: That worked very well! Is is possible to add another condition to that? I want to see if Column AK is blank, and if it is make it a colour.

Comment: Well just add it to the code, i.e =AND(G5<TODAY(),AM5="""DISPATCH""",isblank(AK)=TRUE)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work! Is there another way?

Comment: I just managed to solve it by creating a new condition, so didn't yet try it but thanks for the assistance!